# Optimising Multiple Joins to the same table MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query which joins in the same table (user_status) multiple times in order to pull back different status information. The overall goal of this query is to turn it in to a view. I believe that these joins are causing latency in the query run time, which is causing the query to hang. I am trying to optimise the query as much as possible, but don't know of another way of doing this except to have all of these joins. The joins are left joins as I want to see null values being returned aswell. The where clause filter is to return data for a timeline of up to 370 days ago. I will paste my query below; any suggestions would be really appreciated:

```
SELECT 
    c.id AS customer_id,
    c.priority AS priority,
    c.create_date AS create_date,
    u.login AS login,
    c.due_date AS due_date,
    ts.user_status AS status,
    cts.status AS current_status,
    cts.id AS status_id,
    w.name AS workflow_name,
    c.summary AS summary,
    cfi.added_by AS acknowledged_by,
    CONCAT(dispatch_user.first_name,' ',dispatch_user.last_name) AS dispatch_user, 
    CONCAT(dispatched_user.first_name,' ',dispatched_user.last_name) AS acknowledged,
    CONCAT(last_update_by.first_name,' ',last_update_by.last_name) AS manager_last_updated_by,
    c.updated_date AS updated_date,
    CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) AS last_updated_by,
    ts_new.status_date AS new_dt,
    ts_initial.status_date AS initial_dt,
    ts_assigned.status_date AS assigned_dt,
    ts_investigating.status_date AS investigating_dt,
    ts_resolved.status_date AS resolved_dt,
    ts_pending_closure.status_date AS pending_closure_dt,
    ts_closed.status_date AS closed_dt,
    IF(user_visit.status IS NOT NULL, 'Yes', 'No') AS user_visit,
    fftr.reason AS reason,
    fftr.notes AS resolution,
FROM customer c
JOIN form1 AS tcv ON (c.id = tcv.customer_id)
JOIN user_status AS cts ON (c.current_status_id = cts.id)
JOIN user AS u ON (u.id = cts.status_by_id)
LEFT JOIN user_status AS ts ON (ts.workflow_state = cts.status)
LEFT JOIN change_info AS cfi ON cfi.customer_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN user_status AS dispatch_status ON dispatch_status.customer_id = c.id AND dispatch_status.status = 'FTD'
LEFT JOIN user AS dispatch_user ON dispatch_user.id = dispatch_status.status_by_id
LEFT JOIN user_status AS assigned_ft_dis ON assigned_ft_dis.customer_id = c.id AND assigned_ft_dis.status = 'ASSIGNED - FTD'
LEFT JOIN user_status AS assigned_ft_dis_rx ON assigned_ft_dis_rx.customer_id = c.id AND assigned_ft_dis_rx.status = 'ASSIGNED - FT'
LEFT JOIN user AS dispatched_user ON dispatched_user.id = assigned_ft_dis_rx.status_by_id
LEFT JOIN user_status AS last_update_status ON last_update_status.id = c.current_status_id
LEFT JOIN user last_update_by ON last_update_by.id = last_update_status.status_by_id
LEFT JOIN user_status AS ts_new ON c.id = ts_new.customer_id AND ts_new.status LIKE 'NEW%'
LEFT JOIN user_status AS ts_initial ON c.id = ts_initial_diagnosis.customer_id AND ts_initial_diagnosis.status LIKE 'INITIAL SOLUTION%'
LEFT JOIN user_status AS ts_assigned ON c.id = ts_assigned.customer_id AND ts_assigned.status LIKE 'ASSIGNED%'
LEFT JOIN user_status AS ts_investigating ON c.id = ts_investigating.customer_id AND ts_investigating.status LIKE 'INVESTIGATING%'
LEFT JOIN user_status AS ts_resolved ON c.id = ts_resolved.customer_id AND ts_resolved.status LIKE 'RESOLVED%'
LEFT JOIN user_status AS ts_pending_closure ON c.id = ts_pending_closure.customer_id AND ts_pending_closure.status LIKE 'PENDING CLOSURE%'
LEFT JOIN user_status AS ts_closed ON c.id = ts_closed.customer_id AND ts_closed.status LIKE 'CLOSED%'
LEFT JOIN user_status AS user_visit ON c.id = user_visit.customer_id AND user_visit.status = 'RESOLVED – FT'
LEFT JOIN change AS tc_fftr ON c.id = tc_fftr.customer_id AND tc_fftr.contents LIKE 'Resolution%'
LEFT JOIN form4 AS fftr ON fftr.change_id = tc_fftr.id
WHERE
    c.create_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 370 DAY)
```

Comment: Has it ever run successfully?Post the explain plan

Answer (score 2):

First, the query as listed would not have run as you don't have a "w" alias, and have a trailing comma after the last field.  I have rewritten (slightly) for readability and relationships to each other and changed a few "aliases".

```
SELECT 
      c.id as customer_id,
      c.priority as priority,
      c.create_date as create_date,
      u.login as login,
      c.due_date as due_date,
      ts.user_status as status,
      cts.status as current_status,
      cts.id as status_id,
      w.name as workflow_name,
      c.summary as summary,
      cfi.added_by as acknowledged_by,
      concat(du.first_name,' ',du.last_name) as dispatch_user, 
      concat(disU.first_name,' ',disU.last_name) as acknowledged,
      concat(updBy.first_name,' ',updBy.last_name) as manager_last_updated_by,
      c.updated_date as updated_date,
      concat(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) as last_updated_by,
      ts_new.status_date as new_dt,
      tsi.status_date as initial_dt,
      tsa.status_date as assigned_dt,
      tsinv.status_date as investigating_dt,
      tsres.status_date as resolved_dt,
      tspc.status_date as pending_closure_dt,
      ts_closed.status_date as closed_dt,
      IF(uv.status IS NOT NULL, 'Yes', 'No') as user_visit,
      fftr.reason as reason,
      fftr.notes as resolution
   FROM
      customer c
         join form1 tcv 
            on (c.id = tcv.customer_id)

         join user_status cts 
            on c.current_status_id = cts.id
            join user u 
               on cts.status_by_id = u.id 
            left join user_status ts 
               on cts.status = ts.workflow_state

         left join change_info cfi 
            on c.id = cfi.customer_id

         left join user_status ds 
            on c.id = ds.customer_id 
            and ds.status = 'FTD'
            left join user du 
               on ds.status_by_id = du.id

         left join user_status ftDis 
            on c.id = ftDis.customer_id 
            and ftDis.status = 'ASSIGNED - FTD'

         left join user_status rx 
            on c.id = rx.customer_id 
            and rx.status = 'ASSIGNED - FT'
            left join user disU 
               on rx.status_by_id = disU.id

         left join user_status lus 
            ON c.current_status_id = lus.id
            left join user updBy 
               on lus.status_by_id = updBy.id

         left join user_status ts_new 
            on c.id = ts_new.customer_id 
            and ts_new.status like 'NEW%'

         left join user_status tsi
            on c.id = tsi.customer_id 
            and tsi.status like 'INITIAL SOLUTION%'

         left join user_status tsa 
            on c.id = tsa.customer_id 
            and tsa.status like 'ASSIGNED%'

         left join user_status tsinv 
            on c.id = tsinv.customer_id 
            and tsinv.status like 'INVESTIGATING%'

         left join user_status tsres 
            on c.id = tsres.customer_id 
            and tsres.status like 'RESOLVED%'

         left join user_status tspc 
            on c.id = tspc.customer_id 
            and tspc.status like 'PENDING CLOSURE%'

         left join user_status ts_closed 
            on c.id = ts_closed.customer_id 
            and ts_closed.status like 'CLOSED%'

         left join user_status uv 
            on c.id = uv.customer_id 
            and uv.status = 'RESOLVED – FT'

         left join change tc_fftr 
            ON c.id = tc_fftr.customer_id 
            and tc_fftr.contents LIKE 'Resolution%'
            left join form4 fftr 
               ON tc_fftr.id = fftr.change_id 
   WHERE
      c.create_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 370 DAY)
   GROUP BY 
      customer_id
```

I would ensure the following compound indexes on your tables...

```
table        index
customer     (create_date, id)
form1        (customer_id)
change_info  (customer_id, added_by)
user_status  (id, status_by_id, status )
user         (id, first_name, last_name)
user_status  (customer_id, status, status_date, status_by_id )
change       (customer_id, contents, id )
form4        (change_id)
```

Also, it appears you were not even using the assigned_ft_dis (changed alias to ftDis)

then, in your join after the "form1" of...

```
     join user_status cts 
        on c.current_status_id = cts.id
        join user u 
           on cts.status_by_id = u.id 
        left join user_status ts 
           on cts.status = ts.workflow_state
```

why are you re-joining based on the cts.status to the user_status table again by alias "ts".  IF you have 10k records with status "NEW", you are left-joining to all of those records for the workflow_state.  You have nothing associated to the customer ID.  But since you are prior in the chain of joins, joined by the current_status_id (which I can only GUESS is the auto-increment ID of the user_status table).  Is this a mistake?  Are you trying to get some description for the "workflow_state".  I believe this one component is a big hit on your performance.  Is there a different TABLE (alias "w" for the workflow_state) NOT accurately reflected here?

Now, a possible rewrite.  Do a single join to the user status and user table to determine the respective status elements and by whom and doing case/when for the criteria... something like...  I am using "US" for User_Status alias and "U2" for generic "User" reference for each corresponding "user status" entry.  Now, notice all the case/when instances.  Since I am only joining to the status and then user table without specific criteria, I can apply the criteria at the FIELD condition level and either be null, or applicable and grab both the date and who of the action.

```
SELECT 
      c.id as customer_id,
      c.priority as priority,
      c.create_date as create_date,
      u.login as login,
      c.due_date as due_date,
      ts.user_status as status,
      cts.status as current_status,
      cts.id as status_id,
      w.name as workflow_name,
      c.summary as summary,

      MAX( case when US.status = 'FTD' then US.Status_Date END ) as dispatch_date, 
      MAX( case when US.status = 'FTD' then concat(U2.first_name,' ',U2.last_name) END ) as dispatch_user, 

      MAX( case when US.status = 'ASSIGNED - FTD' then US.Status_Date END ) as assigned_date, 
      MAX( case when US.status = 'ASSIGNED - FTD' then concat(U2.first_name,' ',U2.last_name) END ) as assigned_user, 

      MAX( case when US.status = 'ASSIGNED - FT' then US.Status_Date END ) as assigned2_date, 
      MAX( case when US.status = 'ASSIGNED - FT' then concat(U2.first_name,' ',U2.last_name) END ) as assigned2_user, 

      MAX( case when US.status like 'NEW%' then US.Status_Date END ) as new_date, 
      MAX( case when US.status like 'NEW%' then concat(U2.first_name,' ',U2.last_name) END ) as new_user, 

      MAX( case when US.status like 'INITIAL SOLUTION%' then US.Status_Date END ) as solution_date, 
      MAX( case when US.status like 'INITIAL SOLUTION%' then concat(U2.first_name,' ',U2.last_name) END ) as solution_user, 

      MAX( case when US.status like 'ASSIGNED%' then US.Status_Date END ) as assigned_date, 
      MAX( case when US.status like 'ASSIGNED%' then concat(U2.first_name,' ',U2.last_name) END ) as assigned_user, 

      MAX( case when US.status like 'INVESTIGATING%' then US.Status_Date END ) as investigate_date, 
      MAX( case when US.status like 'INVESTIGATING%' then concat(U2.first_name,' ',U2.last_name) END ) as investigate_user, 

      MAX( case when US.status like 'RESOLVED%' then US.Status_Date END ) as resolved_date, 
      MAX( case when US.status like 'RESOLVED%' then concat(U2.first_name,' ',U2.last_name) END ) as resolved_user, 

      MAX( case when US.status like 'PENDING CLOSURE%' then US.Status_Date END ) as pendClose_date, 
      MAX( case when US.status like 'PENDING CLOSURE%' then concat(U2.first_name,' ',U2.last_name) END ) as pendClose_user, 

      MAX( case when US.status like 'CLOSED%' then US.Status_Date END ) as closed_date, 
      MAX( case when US.status like 'CLOSED%' then concat(U2.first_name,' ',U2.last_name) END ) as closed_user, 

      MAX( case when US.status = 'RESOLVED - FT' then US.Status_Date END ) as resolved_date, 
      MAX( case when US.status = 'RESOLVED - FT' then concat(U2.first_name,' ',U2.last_name) END ) as resolved_user, 

      c.updated_date as updated_date,
      concat(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) as last_updated_by,
      IF(uv.status IS NOT NULL, 'Yes', 'No') as user_visit,
      fftr.reason as reason,
      fftr.notes as resolution
   FROM
      customer c
         left join user_status US
            on c.id = US.customer_id 
            left join user U2 
               on US.status_by_id = U2.id

         join form1 tcv 
            on (c.id = tcv.customer_id)

         join user_status cts 
            on c.current_status_id = cts.id
            join user u 
               on cts.status_by_id = u.id 
            left join user_status ts 
               on cts.status = ts.workflow_state

         left join change_info cfi 
            on c.id = cfi.customer_id

         left join user_status lus 
            ON c.current_status_id = lus.id
            left join user updBy 
               on lus.status_by_id = updBy.id

         left join change tc_fftr 
            ON c.id = tc_fftr.customer_id 
            and tc_fftr.contents LIKE 'Resolution%'
            left join form4 fftr 
               ON tc_fftr.id = fftr.change_id 
   WHERE
      c.create_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 370 DAY)
   GROUP BY 
      customer_id
```

This still may not work completely, but I am sure MOST of it WILL work and accommodate almost all of what you are trying to get even though I am getting a few more details (pair of both dates and who of the corresponding status actions).